# How to rename (or translate) widget name in Orchard

Tags: widget, orchardcms, rename, translate

I need to translate widget name in Widgets section of Orchard administration.

Any hint/tips how and where to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Really dont know how my question is not clear/how can I do more research. I tried to google something about this topic and found nothing. I tried to search whole Orchard solution in Visual Studio to find names of Widgets and wasn't successful :( I found only that there can be some .txt files in folders of widgets (where is possible to define name of Widget), but since I use some "special" widgets that are stored in \Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Alanis.Orchard\Views\Parts and these are just .cshtml files (not stored in separated folders) I'm really not sure what to do or where to search...

Answer (score 0):

All widgets are content types too. You can go to the admin -> Content Definition -> Search for the widget you want to rename -> edit. There you can specify which name you want to give it.

Comment: WOW, I really didn't expect it to be so easy. THANK YOU, I was a little desperate whether it is even possible to achieve :)

Comment: Now I see that it changed names in layers overview (Menu -> Widgets), but when I click to some zone to add new widget, names in widgets list are not changed :( How to change it there?